# How to hide WordPress default links in source page?

Tags: wordpress

In every WordPress site, when you see at the source page, you see the links wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes that makes clear to the person viewing the source page that is a WordPress site. I have searched a while ago about how to hide those, but I can not find anything that would help. How can I change these folders?

Comment: It could get very messy but perhaps look into either a) renaming these folders or b) moving your content (images and files) outside the 'wp-content' folder. That said, I'd recommend against doing both of these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible nor does there appear to be will to modify the `wp-admin` folder structure.

You can rename the `wp-content` folder, following a guide like [How To Rename Your WordPress WP-Content Directory](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/renaming-wordpress-wp-content-folder/). A quick summary of the guide:

After physically renaming your `wp-content` folder to `assets`, add the following to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define ('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'assets');  
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME) ;  
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'); 
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);  
define('PLUGINDIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME . '/plugins' );
```

And if you have any must-use plugins you should add the following lines:

```
define('MUPLUGINDIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME . '/mu-plugins' );
```

Then you'll see your plugins, themes, and uploads properly within WordPress.

If you are still really interested in changing the `wp-admin` folder, you should review the recommendations from from this post "[Can I rename the wp-admin folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder)" with the answer from @MikeSchinkel.

1. Present your case [on wp-hackers](http://lists.automattic.com/mailman/listinfo/wp-hackers) but be forewarned your use-case better be good and not "security through obscurity" or it will get shot down as above.
2. Present your argument in [a trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/newticket) with the same caveats.
3. Even better, upload [a patch](http://asymptomatic.net/2005/12/03/586/how-to-patch-wordpress) to trac that enables your desired functionality. It's much harder to say no when the work has already been done (but of course, they do have a preference for saying "no" a lot more often than they say "yes" so be forewarned.)

Comment: Maybe constants `PLUGINDIR` and `MUPLUGINDIR` should be redefined too as they include "wp-content" literally in the path, otherwise scripts using them wont work. Check `\wp-includes\default-constants.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll update the answer with those constants as well when I get home.